# SQL variable for dynamic Table name change with get date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql which I can't get working, there is a table which gets created daily with the format of YYYYMMDD at the end of the table name each day.
Here is the SQL:

```
    DECLARE @var INT



    SET @var = CAST(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),GETDATE()-1,112) AS int)

    SELECT @VAR


    SELECT
    CASE WHEN LEN("AssociatedData") = 0 OR "AssociatedData" IS NULL THEN '*Unknown*' ELSE AssociatedData END AS AssociatedData,
    "CallEvent",
    CASE WHEN LEN("CallEventName") = 0 OR "CallEventName" IS NULL THEN '*Unknown*' ELSE CallEventName END AS CallEventName,
    "CallID",
    CASE WHEN LEN("Destination") = 0 OR "Destination" IS NULL THEN '*Unknown*' ELSE Destination END AS Destination,
    CASE WHEN LEN("EventData") = 0 OR "EventData" IS NULL THEN '*Unknown*' ELSE EventData END AS EventData,
    "FirstEventTimestamp",
    "SequenceNumber",
    "Source",
    CASE WHEN LEN("TelsetLoginID") = 0 OR "TelsetLoginID" IS NULL THEN '*Unknown*' ELSE TelsetLoginID END AS TelsetLoginID,
    "Time",
    "Timestamp"
    FROM concat(eCallByCallStat,@var)
```

I need to get this working as a SQL query rather than a StoredProcedure.

Is this possible at all to append the datekey straight after the tablename.

Thank you

Comment: No, it is not possible.  You need to use dynamic SQL.  Or, change the job that creates the table to *insert* the rows into a master table.

Comment: How would the dynamic SQL look like in SQL thank you?

Comment: Here is a link to the [Microsoft documentation on dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql).  Creating a new table each day complicates query writing.  Have you considered adding a date column to a fixed table name?

Comment: Its just how the system is I am afraid, it created a new table each day with the date after the name. I just need to query it and send the rows into a staging table with previous days accumulating them.

Comment: @abs786123 . . . You explicitly state "I need to get this working as a SQL query rather than a StoredProcedure."  I interpret that to mean that dynamic SQL is not a viable solution.

Comment: Sorry it is, but, the stem wont allow me to create an SP. Dynamic SQL will be okay as a Query. Its not a SQL server database by the way so the SPexecute that uses Dynamic may not work. But if you can write an SQL query I can run as a script would be great. I would really appreciative your help

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @tsql VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @var DATE = GETDATE() - 1

SET @tsql = '
SELECT
  [AssociatedData] = CASE WHEN LEN( [AssociatedData] ) > 0 THEN [AssociatedData] ELSE ''*Unknown*'' END,
  [CallEvent],
  [CallEventName] = CASE WHEN LEN( [CallEventName] ) > 0 THEN [CallEventName] ELSE ''*Unknown*'' END,
  [CallID],
  [Destination] = CASE WHEN LEN( [Destination] ) > 0 THEN [Destination] ELSE ''*Unknown*'' END,
  [EventData] = CASE WHEN LEN( [EventData] ) > 0 THEN [EventData] ELSE ''*Unknown*'' END,
  [FirstEventTimestamp],
  [SequenceNumber],
  [Source],
  [TelsetLoginID] = CASE WHEN LEN( [TelsetLoginID] ) > 0 THEN [TelsetLoginID] ELSE ''*Unknown*'' END,
  [Time],
  [Timestamp]
FROM 
  ' + CONCAT( 'eCallByCallStat', CONVERT( VARCHAR, @var, 112 ) )

PRINT @tsql
EXEC sp_executesql @tsql
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting this message Msg 214, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.